# Jasmine Asynchronous Support

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to understand the new jasmine async feature. I understand how an optional function can be passed to beforeEach that should be called after asych operation has been completed. However, what exactly is the purpose of calling done in the following snippet:

```
it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    value++;
    expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    done();
  });
```

Is the only purpose to signal that the spec execution has been completed? Is it necessary to pass done to the function?